# What things should I consider before moving from CF9 to Railo?

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I've been using ColdFusion 9 along with the ColdFusion on Wheels Framework for about 6 months now. I still consider myself a beginner, but I am comfortable doing most things I need to.

I recently started writing full CF Script components, and I'm loving the cleanliness of the syntax. I am disappointed to lose some of the simplicity afforded by CFQuery, CFLoop, and so on... but I can live without this for now.

Recently, a few people have mentioned that Railo has better CFScript support. I'm considering switching for that reason.

What things should I keep in mind, and how do the two platforms stack against one another in terms of functionality and ease of use?

Comment: Mel, it sounds like you really like CF9, why are you considering moving to Railo?

Comment: @Mike, to be honest I don't have an objective reason. It appears to me that those I speak to about CF like it more. Now that certainly is a stupid reason to switch, but I would assume they know something I don't!

Comment: Hey Mel, never assume that others know more than you do :). As my son's karate instructor says, don't watch the person next to you to practice your form, because they may be doing wrong. Always do the research to make sure it'll fit your needs (and this question is a great start to that). By all means listen to others to begin your research. Trust, but verify.

Comment: +1 what Daniel Short said. Plus, if you have access to CF9 already, you'd be silly not to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the things you need to look for as far as differences between Railo and ColdFusion. This page lists all of the things that Adobe CF has that Railo doesn't, and vice versa:

http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/documentation/compatibility/cfml-compatibility/

Comment: Warning that this is an **incomplete** list. Unfortunately the documentation for Railo is exceedingly poor. For example, their own docs say that you can use CFPDF to add headers or footers. This is not the case. The CFPDF tag in Railo does not support many of the actions in ACF.

Answer (score 5):

Mel,

well the easiest way to try it out is to create a mapping called "/" that points to "/" and then compile this mapping from the admin. That should give you a good result on how compatible your code is in terms of compilation.

And a good thing to consider. If you are really happy with CF9, stick with it. You never change a winning team. I am of course proud of Railo and convinced it is the best CFML engine. But I am biased and you should only consider a switch if it is really necessary for different reasons. Costs, performance, memory footprint. But again, if your system runs very well on CF9, just save the money and do something else with it.

Gert Franz
Railo Technologies GmbH

Answer (score 4):

Be careful making decisions based on anecdotes!  ColdFusion 9.0.1 brought even more support for cfscript:

> Support for the following:
>
> for-in construct (for arrays) in CFScript
>
> var declaration within for loop in CFScript
>
> Function argument metadata
> Function equivalents for cfile action="upload" (FileUpload) and cffile action="uploadall" (FileUploadAll)
>
> The following script functions have been implemented as CFCs:
>
> dbinfo
>
> imap
>
> pop
>
> ldap
>
> feed

From:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/847/cpsid_84725.html

Comment: Some of these, Railo has had for awhile now before CF9 came out. Out of the ones you listed, Railo imap is different, there is no FileUploadAll. I think that's it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing much work with PDF generation (CFdocument) or charting (cfchart), you'll want to try these out in Railo and see how they compare to what you are currently getting with Adobe CF.  When I tested charting in Railo I found the Adobe CF engine to produce much nicer looking graphs.  I think the PDF engine is better in Adobe CF also.

Comment: The PDF engine in CF9 is absolute garbage. It's based on the ICE Browser, and not even the most current implementation. Even Adobe's list of officially supported CSS properties isn't even correct (for example, a lot of the "page-break" properties don't work).

This one feature has been the bane of my existence for months. I've done a lot of work with it, and it is the most aggravating aspect of my job. It's frustrating for our management, our clients, and our developers. Adobe should stop advertising this as a feature of CF it's so broken.